# Want to use one int array in Main Function from thread's run() function

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class fraktal extends JFrame   {

 public fraktal (String args[]) {
  calc = new Calculator(632,453,raster, this);    
  }
 calc.start();


 } 
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  new fraktal(args);
 }

}

class Calculator extends Thread {
 public Calculator(int sx, int sy, WritableRaster r, JFrame p) {

 public void run() {  
  int[] dataArray = new int[3600000];
  raster.getPixels(0,0,32,53,dataArray);  
  //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dataArray));    
 } 
}
```

I wanna use "dataArray" , a int array in Main, how Can I get it?
Thanks indeed!

Comment: You are using that array already, what is the problem with your code?

Comment: I want to use dataArray in Main fuction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here in your code there are many mistakes, if you just want to use dataArray in Main method here is snippet. try correcting mistakes and also check the link given

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;


public class fraktal extends JFrame   {
 int[] dataArray;
 public fraktal (String args[]) {
  Calculator calc = new Calculator(dataArray);    
  calc.start();
  }




 public static void main(String args[]) {
 fraktal ob =  new fraktal(args);
 System.out.println(ob.dataArray);
 }

}

class Calculator extends Thread {
 int[] dataArray;

 public Calculator(int[] dataArray) {
   this.dataArray = dataArray;
 }
 public void run() {    
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dataArray));    
 } 
}
```

[Java Variable Scope Documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html)

Comment: so,can I ask, why after  this.dataArray = dataArray, modifying dataArray in run() function can reflect to dataArray declared in main? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add getters to Calculator and fraktal. Smt like getMyArray().